# Could the intentional killing of civilians in primarily Christian Ukraine be included in symbolism within the book of Revelation?

Tags: eschatology, revelation, symbolism

On the [English Wikipedia page for Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine), the following demographics are presented:

[image]

Since the country is 87.3% Christian, the intentional targeting of civilians constitutes the intentional targeting of Christians and is happening right now, right around the corner.

Could this have been foretold in Revelation?  Is it hiding there in the "horns" passage in Revelation 17

The seven heads = seven mountains -- could these be countries?

The ten horns = ten kings.  Vladimir Putin is basically the king, isn't he?

"These will make war with the Lamb" -- isn't this what we are seeing right now? Christian genocide?

[Revelation 17:3-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+17%3A3-6&version=NKJV)

> New King James Version 3 So he carried me away in the Spirit into the
> wilderness. And **I saw a woman sitting on a scarlet beast which was
> full of names of blasphemy, having seven heads and ten horns.** 4 The
> woman was arrayed in purple and scarlet, and adorned with gold and
> precious stones and pearls, having in her hand a golden cup full of
> abominations and the filthiness of [a]her fornication. 5 And on her
> forehead a name was written:
>
> MYSTERY, BABYLON THE GREAT, THE MOTHER OF HARLOTS AND OF THE
> ABOMINATIONS OF THE EARTH.
>
> 6 **I saw the woman, drunk with the blood of the saints** and with the
> blood of the martyrs of Jesus. And when I saw her, I marveled with
> great amazement.

[Revelation 17:9-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+17%3A9-14&version=NKJV)

> New King James Version 9 “Here is the mind which has wisdom: **The
> seven heads are seven mountains on which the woman sits.** 10 There
> are also seven kings. Five have fallen, one is, and the other has not
> yet come. And when he comes, he must continue a short time. 11 The
> beast that was, and is not, is himself also the eighth, and is of the
> seven, and is going to [a]perdition.
>
> 12 **“The ten horns which you saw are ten kings** who have received no
> kingdom as yet, but they receive authority for one hour as kings with
> the beast. 13 These are of one mind, and they will give their power
> and authority to the beast. 14 **These will make war with the Lamb**,
> and the Lamb will overcome them, for He is Lord of lords and King of
> kings; and those who are with Him are called, chosen, and faithful.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only time will tell. The ethnic and religious statistics are interesting.  With regard to the religious element, it is worth noting that there are two distinct denominations that claim to be the "true" Ukranian Orthodox Church.

The oldest is ***the Ukrainian Orthodox Church***, and the Moscow Patriarchate is a branch of ***the Russian Orthodox Church***.  Its Patriarch - Kirill of Moscow - has often spoken on the ties that link the people of Ukraine and Russia. I believe that Mr. Putin, who claims to be a Christian and wears a cross around his neck, is a supporter of the Russian Orthodox Church and the Ukrainian Orthodox Church.

***The Orthodox Church of Ukraine*** was formed in 2018 after decades of work towards a national church. It ***emphasises its independence from Russia.*** It was recognised as an equal member of the worldwide communion of Orthodox churches by Bartholomew I of Constantinople (he's the current 'spiritual leader' of Eastern Orthodoxy.)

This new, self-governing denomination is apparently seen as a challenge to Moscow. The Moscow Patriarchate broke communion with Constantinople after Bartholomew recognised the Orthodox Church of Ukraine.

Putin has written that Russians and Ukrainians are one people and should be united by one church.  He apparently claimed that the creation of the new Orthodox church of Ukraine was an attack on 'spiritual unity'.  ***Ukrainian Orthodox and Catholic leaders accuse the Russian Orthodox Church of complicity in Putin's aggression towards Ukraine.***  Source: March 2022 "Record" magazine, published in Edinburgh, Scotland.

The BBC news (on 2 March) interviewed believers in their gold encrusted cathedral in Kyiv. The people interviewed declared their staunch faith in God protecting them from the evil aggressor (Russia).

It is worth remembering that Christians are being persecuted throughout the world by governments in China, North Korea as well as many Islamic governments.  This is not new.  The fact that there is friction between the Russian Orthodox Church and the Orthodox Church of Ukraine may be significant, but Christians do well to remember that it is the Lord God Almighty who is Sovereign and that His timing is always perfect.

Update: 2019 demographics of religion in Ukraine:

> In 2019, 82% of Ukrainians were Christians; out of which 72.7% declared themselves to be Orthodox, 8.8% Greek Rite Catholics, 2.3% Protestants and 0.9% Latin Rite Catholics. 2.3% other Christians. Judaism, Islam and Hinduism were the religions of 0.2% of the population each.

> According to the KIIS study, roughly 58.3% of the Ukrainian Orthodox population were members of the Orthodox Church of Ukraine, and 25.4% were members of the Ukrainian Orthodox Church of the Moscow Patriarchate.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine#Religion

Yes, the intentional killing of civilians in primarily Christian Ukraine could be included in the symbolism within the book of Revelation but trying to pin down the specifics is an exercise in futility.

Answer (score -1):

#### Probably not.

1 Thessalonians 5:2-3 says:

> For you are fully aware that the Day of the Lord will come like a thief in the night. While people are saying, “Peace and security,” destruction will come upon them suddenly, like labor pains on a pregnant woman, and they will not escape.

That is, the Second Coming will occur in a time of peace and security, in addition to occurring when nobody will expect it. If you're asking "could this be a sign of the Second Coming", the answer is almost always "no", because if somebody is expecting it, the that means that "nobody will expect it" isn't true.

Comment: Except that nobody would expect it to come when they're expecting it -- that would be too tricky.

Comment: The very next verse:  "But ye, brethren, are not in darkness, that that day should overtake you as a thief."

Comment: @MikeBorden Because you're supposed to be living a life such that it could come at any time, not because you'll know the hour or day.

Comment: Yes but that does not mean we are as clueless as those in darkness.  2 Thes 2:5 indicates that we have some things to watch for.  Not to mention that the fact that we are expecting that day shows that it will not overtake us as a thief.